No agarra el codigo y la pantalla se pone en color negro cuando se presiona control b
Lo que estoy haciendo es un juego que reconoce la cara para hacer el movimiento de un avión; lo que yo estoy intentando hacer es que tenga una pantalla antes de la pantalla que dice "presiona enter para continuar". En esa pantalla le agregare un botón, según yo lo intente, pero por lo q veo no agarra y se queda en negro.
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from pygame.locals import *
from webcam import Webcam
from enemy import Enemy
from events import *
from background import Background
import globals
import random

import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import math

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.started = False
        self.instruction_page = True

        #Facemesh
        self.mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
        self.mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Misiles")

        self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
        self.smaller_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 22)
        self.background = Background()

        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.last_frame_time = self.start_time
        self.player = Player()
        self.movement = 0

        #Timers
        self.enemy_timer = 1000
        pygame.time.set_timer(ADD_ENEMY, self.enemy_timer)

        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.lost = False
        self.score = 0

        self.webcam = Webcam().start()
        
        self.max_face_surf_height=0
        self.face_left_x = 0
        self.face_right_x = 0
        self.face_top_y = 0
        self.face_bottom_y = 0

    def update(self, delta_time):
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    self.running = False

        if self.lost or not self.started:
            for event in events:
                #Cuando perdimos o no hemos empezado, ENTER comienza el juego
                if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RETURN:
                    if self.instruction_page:
                        self.instruction_page = False
                    else:
                        self.initialize()
                        self.started = True
        else:
            #Aumentar la velocidad segun el tiempo qu ehemos durado
            globals.game_speed = 1 + ( (pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time) / 1000) * .1
            self.score = self.score + (delta_time * globals.game_speed)

            for event in events:
                if event.type == ADD_ENEMY:
                    #Agregar 1 o 2 enemigos
                    num = random.randint(1,2)
                    for e in range(num):
                        enemy = Enemy()
                        self.enemies.add(enemy)

                    #Actualizar el timer que define cuando aparecera un nuevo enemigo
                    self.enemy_timer = 1000 - ((globals.game_speed - 1) * 100)
                    if self.enemy_timer < 50: self.enemy_timer = 50
                    pygame.time.set_timer(ADD_ENEMY, int(self.enemy_timer))

            self.player.update(self.movement, delta_time)
            self.enemies.update(delta_time)
            self.process_collisions()
            self.background.update(delta_time)

    def process_collisions(self):
        #Colisiones para este juego los hacemos con mascaras
        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.enemies, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
        if collide:
            self.lost = True

    def render(self):
        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

        self.background.render(self.screen)
        
        if self.webcam.lastFrame is not None and not self.instruction_page:
            self.render_camera()

        self.screen.blit(self.player.surf, self.player.rect)

        for e in self.enemies:
            self.screen.blit(e.surf, e.rect)

        display_score = round(self.score/1000)
        text_score = self.font.render('Score: ' + str(display_score), True, (255,255,255))
        scoreTextRect = text_score.get_rect()
        scoreTextRect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT-5
        scoreTextRect.left = 5
        self.screen.blit(text_score, scoreTextRect)

        if self.lost:
            game_over_text = self.font.render('GAME OVER :(', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
            game_over_text_rect = game_over_text.get_rect()
            game_over_text_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
            self.screen.blit(game_over_text, game_over_text_rect)

            retry_text = self.smaller_font.render('Presiona Enter para reintentar', True, (200,200,200), (0,0,0))
            retry_text_rect = retry_text.get_rect()
            retry_text_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2) + 40)
            self.screen.blit(retry_text, retry_text_rect)

        if not self.started:
            if self.instruction_page:
                instruction_text = self.font.render('Instrucciones:', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
                instruction_text_rect = instruction_text.get_rect()
                instruction_text_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 100)
                self.screen.blit(instruction_text, instruction_text_rect)

                instruction_text1 = self.smaller_font.render('Mueve tu cabeza hacia la derecha o izquierda para controlar al jugador', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
                instruction_text1_rect = instruction_text1.get_rect()
                instruction_text1_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 50)
                self.screen.blit(instruction_text1, instruction_text1_rect)

                instruction_text2 = self.smaller_font.render('Evita que los enemigos toquen al jugador', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
                instruction_text2_rect = instruction_text2.get_rect()
                instruction_text2_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 - 20)
                self.screen.blit(instruction_text2, instruction_text2_rect)

                instruction_text3 = self.smaller_font.render('Presiona Enter para comenzar', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
                instruction_text3_rect = instruction_text3.get_rect()
                instruction_text3_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2 + 20)
                self.screen.blit(instruction_text3, instruction_text3_rect)
            else:
                game_start_text = self.font.render('Presiona Enter para comenzar', True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
                game_start_text_rect = game_start_text.get_rect()
                game_start_text_rect.center = (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2)
               

    def loop(self):
        with self.mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
            static_image_mode=False,
            max_num_faces=1,
            min_detection_confidence=0.5,
            refine_landmarks=True
        ) as self.face_mesh:
            while self.running:
                if not self.lost:
                    if not self.webcam.ready():
                        continue
                    self.process_camera()

                time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                delta_time = time - self.last_frame_time
                self.last_frame_time = time
                self.update(delta_time)
                self.render()
                self.clock.tick(60)
            pygame.quit()

    def process_camera(self):
        image = self.webcam.read()
        if image is not None:
            image.flags.writeable = False
            image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            results = self.face_mesh.process(image)
            self.webcam_image = image
            if results.multi_face_landmarks is not None:
                for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:

                    #Coordenadas de la cara (arriba y abajo)
                    top = (face_landmarks.landmark[10].x, face_landmarks.landmark[10].y)
                    bottom = (face_landmarks.landmark[152].x, face_landmarks.landmark[152].y)

                    #Obtener coordenadas del 'cuadrado' de la cara para poder mostrarlo en la pantalla despues
                    self.face_left_x = face_landmarks.landmark[234].x
                    self.face_right_x = face_landmarks.landmark[454].x
                    self.face_top_y = face_landmarks.landmark[10].y
                    self.face_bottom_y = face_landmarks.landmark[152].y

                    #Dejar algo de espacio alrededor
                    self.face_left_x = self.face_left_x - .1
                    self.face_right_x = self.face_right_x + .1
                    self.face_top_y = self.face_top_y - .1
                    self.face_bottom_y = self.face_bottom_y + .1

                    cv2.line(
                        self.webcam_image, 
                        (int(top[0] * self.webcam.width()), int(top[1] * self.webcam.height())),
                        (int(bottom[0] * self.webcam.width()), int(bottom[1] * self.webcam.height())),
                        (0, 255, 0), 3
                    )

                    cv2.circle(self.webcam_image, (int(top[0] * self.webcam.width()), int(top[1] * self.webcam.height())), 8, (0,0,255), -1)
                    cv2.circle(self.webcam_image, (int(bottom[0] * self.webcam.width()), int(bottom[1] * self.webcam.height())), 8, (0,0,255), -1)

                    #Deteccion de angulo
                    self.detect_head_movement(top, bottom)

            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    def detect_head_movement(self, top, bottom):
        radians = math.atan2(bottom[1] - top[1], bottom[0] - top[0])
        degrees = math.degrees(radians)

        #Angulo de deteccion de 70 a 110 (-1 a 1)
        min_degrees = 70
        max_degrees = 110
        degree_range = max_degrees - min_degrees
        
        if degrees < min_degrees: degrees = min_degrees
        if degrees > max_degrees: degrees = max_degrees

        self.movement = ( ((degrees-min_degrees) / degree_range) * 2) - 1

    def render_camera(self):        
        #Limpiar coordenadas del cuadro de la cara
        if self.face_left_x < 0: self.face_left_x = 0
        if self.face_right_x > 1: self.face_right_x = 1
        if self.face_top_y < 0: self.face_top_y = 0
        if self.face_bottom_y > 1: self.face_bottom_y = 1

        face_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(self.webcam_image, (int(self.webcam.width()), int(self.webcam.height())), "BGR")

        face_rect = pygame.Rect(
            int(self.face_left_x*self.webcam.width()),
            int(self.face_top_y*self.webcam.height()), 
            int(self.face_right_x*self.webcam.width()) - int(self.face_left_x*self.webcam.width()),
            int(self.face_bottom_y*self.webcam.height()) - int(self.face_top_y*self.webcam.height())
        )
        
        only_face_surf = pygame.Surface((
            int(self.face_right_x*self.webcam.width()) - int(self.face_left_x*self.webcam.width()),
            int(self.face_bottom_y*self.webcam.height()) - int(self.face_top_y*self.webcam.height())
        ))
        only_face_surf.blit(face_surf, (0,0), face_rect)
        face_ratio = only_face_surf.get_rect().height / only_face_surf.get_rect().width
        face_area_width = 130
        face_area_height = face_area_width * face_ratio
        if (face_area_height > self.max_face_surf_height):
            self.max_face_surf_height = face_area_height
        only_face_surf = pygame.transform.scale(only_face_surf, (int(face_area_width),int(self.max_face_surf_height)))
        self.screen.blit(only_face_surf, only_face_surf.get_rect())


¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Has publicado una gran cantidad de código. Funciona mejor cuando preparas un [mcve] con el que quien quiera responderte pueda reproducir el problema (completo), contenga solo el código esencial para reproducirlo (mínimo) y así tenga un punto de partida para una posible respuesta. Eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.

Quería dedicarte 5 minutitos a tu problema. Pero estoy muy cansado como para buscar el error en un código tan extenso.
